# How can high pitch sound travel less faster?

Tags: waves, acoustics, dispersion

I read these three sentences

Frequency is inversely proportional to wavelength

Frequency increase causes an increase in pitch.

They mean high frequency has small wavelength.
So they travel less farther.
In that case, i should to hear a whistle sound less (high-pitch).

But it is more audible right.
Please help me understand the reason

Comment: [citation:](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-pitch-and-vs-frequency/) _Pitch is not a well-defined concept. Pitch is not a property of the sound wave. The pitch is the hearing sensation created by such a sound wave._ So while frequency is a physical property of sound waves, pitch is somewhat a subjective projection of frequency effect on **your** ears/brain response. So no clean relationship exist between frequency and pitch.

Comment: I mean to ask why do i hear a whistle sound more clearly than other sounds. Whistle sound has a smaller wavelength

Comment: Smaller wavelength does not mean that the wave travels less farther. Your question is based on a wrong assumption

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing two different concepts:

- velocity of the transmission: different velocity of transmission of signals with difference frequency is related to **dispersion**;
- length of transmission: the reduction of intensity of the signal depends on the "shape" of the signal (e.g. amplitude of spherical waves in a non-diffusive medium goes with $1/r$, for plane waves is approximately constant), and on the **diffusion** (or **attenuation**).

**Dispersion.** The speed of sound in air is approximately the same over a wide range of frequency (and amplitude) of the signal, i.e. air behaves as a non-dispersive medium. Sound signals have velocity of transmission equal to $c$, where

$c^2(\rho_0,s_0) = \left(\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_s(\rho_0,s_0)$

**Diffusion.** Sound attenuation can be described by Stokes' law, examining the effects of the volume viscosity on plane waves, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27s_law_of_sound_attenuation. To cut a long story short, air behaves as a **low-pass filter**, attenuating the signals with higher frequency (like many other systems in nature, far from their natural frequencies - resonance).

Anyway, it's likely that the main effect is the "directionality" of the sound wave, i.e. if the sound propagates as a spherical signal, or a plane wave. Have you ever tried that pairs of parabolic mirrors where you whisper something in a focus of one mirror and someone else clearly listen to your whisper in the focus of the other paraboloid?